# PHP - make a request to cloudfare protected site?

Tags: php

I am attempting to download the document of a certain webpage(the stuff you would see if you hit 'view page source'), which has cloudfare protection, then echo it. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    $curlConfig = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6',
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 0
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
    echo(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

It redirects me to this url:

> http://localhost/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?    jschl_vc=7df2b994a588cc3cb3b91ecc95acca7e&pass=1443965612.707-g3h0lQ531e&jschl_answer=377

Of course, I do not have `chk_jschl` on my localhost. How can I work around this?

Comment: Can't you just follow the redirects?

Comment: like I said, it tries to redirect me to something on my localhost I do not have.

Comment: read this https://www.cryptobells.com/bypassing-cloudflares-layer-7-ddos-protection/

Comment: What exactly is your goal, what do you want to do with the source of that page, does it belong to you? Do you have the right to use it? It's probably protected for a reason!

Comment: I am making a plugin for the owner of the site (a forum). It will alert the owner when a post is made in a certain sub-forum.